# DNS automation in a private cloud using DNSJava

Tags: dns, cloud, dnsjava

I am trying to create a DNS service (automation of various DNS operations) to serve our existing private cloud. I am looking for options and ideas to do this. Is there any existing Java API to do this? Please suggest.

I made a research on the possible solutions. I found [DNSJava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/) to be a good solution. But I did not find much documentation/examples. The following are some questions which, when answered, can solve my current problems:

1. How to add NS or A records to zone files?
2. How to print out the contents of a zone file?

I have created a local DNS server for test purpose. It will be really helpful if the examples are given with respect to localhost.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of research, I found a way to modify the zone files with [DNSJava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/). Bind9 should be setup in the server. Required zone files should be created with basic information. Adding and deleting a record in the zone file is straight forward once we have this setup. Please refer to [this](https://sort.symantec.com/public/documents/sfha/6.0/linux/productguides/html/vcs_bundled_agents/ch03s06s06s06.htm) page to generate TSIG key for Bind9. The code that can actually add a record is given below.

```
Name zoneName = null; 
String domain = "your.domain";
String host = "hostname";
DNSRecordType type = DNSRecordType.A;
int ttl = 600;

Lookup lookup = new Lookup(Name.fromString("your.domain"));
Record [] records = lookup.run();
if(records != null) {
   zoneName = records[0].getName();
}
if(zoneName != null) {
    Name hostName = Name.fromString("hostname", zoneName);
    Update update = new Update(zoneName);
    update.add(hostName, Type.value(type.toString()), 600,
                  "192.168.2.50");
    Resolver resolver = new SimpleResolver();
    resolver.setTCP(true);
    resolver.setTSIGKey(new TSIG("your.domain.",
                 "z0pll56C4cwLXYd2HG6WsQ=="));

    Message response1 = resolver.send(update);
    response = response1.getHeader().toString();
}
```

Comment: `DNSRecordType` doesn't exist anymore, you should probably replace by `Type.A` which return already an int.